# I Cannot able to pass the id in route file in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am declaring the above thing in the route for edit of my data.

```
Route::get('editproduct/{id}', 'HomeController@Edit_Product');
```

Above is my editproduct.blade.php page

```
    <?php
$id = $_GET['eid'];
$product_info = DB::select("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `pid` = '".$id."'");
foreach($product_info as $detail)
{
    $actual_image = 'theme/uploads/'.$detail->pimage;
    $product_image = $detail->pimage;
    $product_name = $detail->pname;
    $product_price = $detail->pprice;
}
?>
@include('include/header')
<div class="tab-pane add-product-view" id="profile">
    <form name="add_product" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" action="{{ url('edit-product-process') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-label">Add Image: </div>
        <div class="form-field"><input type="file" name="add_image" id="add_image"  value="{{asset($actual_image)}}" /></div>
        <img src="{{asset($actual_image)}}" width="50" height="50" />

        <div class="form-label">Product Name:</div>
        <div class="form-field"><input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name"  value="{{ $product_name }}"  /></div>

        <div class="form-label">Product Price:</div>
        <div class="form-field"><input type="text" name="product_price" id="product_price" value="{{ $product_price }}" /></div>

        <div class="btn btn-primary"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Product"</div>
    </form>
</div>
@include('include/footer')
```

This is My HomeController.blade.php

```
public function Edit_Product($id){
        return View::make('editproduct')->with('id', $id);
    }
    public function edit_product_process(Request $request){
        $prd_id = $request->pid;
        $imageTempName = $request->file('add_image')->getPathname();
        $imageName = $request->file('add_image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = base_path() . '/theme/uploads/';
        $request->file('add_image')->move($path , $imageName);
        $remember_token = $request->_token;
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $pname = $request->product_name;
        $pprice = $request->product_price;


        DB::table('product')->where('pid',$prd_id)->update(
        array(
            'pimage' => $imageName,
            'pname' => $pname,
            'pprice' => $pprice,
            'remember_token' => $remember_token,
            'created_at' => $date,
            'updated_at' => $date,
        )
        );
        return redirect('dashboard');
    }
```

I am getting the below error, Please anyone can be able to help me, I am new at laravel.

```
page is not found
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting this error when you're trying to submit the form, you should check you route. It should look like this:

```
Route::post('edit-product-process', 'HomeController@edit_product_process');
```

Also, to pass an ID into `edit_product_process` you need to add field with ID into the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">
```

And then you can get it in `edit_product_process` with `$request->id`

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexey Mezenin, it wordked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be as:

```
Route::get('editproduct/{id}', 'HomeController@Edit_Product')->name('product.edit');
```

Then you can use it as:

```
{{ route('product.edit', ['id' => $id]) }}
```

**But it's a terrible practice to use DB queries in views.**

Please do read more about [queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) and [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Controller Name Why r using blade in that.This is bad practice.HomeController.blade.php